# Accessing arrays dynamically

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on a project. I've a situation here. I'm having arrays with similar names consider `arr1`, `arr2`, `arr3`, etc.

Now I know the array number which I'm supposed to use let it be `2`. Is there any way in c# to make the array name dynamically through strings and use it.
Like in flash action script we can do

```
_root["arr"+i][0]
```

here i contains the array number to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is something what JavaScript or dynamic languages have, but their array types are rather associative arrays. To reach the functionality you want you can use Dictionary:

```
    var arr1 = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    var arr2 = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    var arr3 = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };

    var _root = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();
    _root.Add("arr1", arr1);
    _root.Add("arr2", arr2);
    _root.Add("arr3", arr3);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
      int arrElem = _root["arr" + i][0];
    }
```

Note the expression within the for loop, it's like what you were asking for.

Answer (score 2):

No - you cannot access variable names dynamically.  You can use reflection to dynamically access *properties*, but not variables.  I would use a `List<int[]>` like so:

```
List<int[]> arrList = new List<int[]> {arr1, arr2, arr3);
int[] arr = arrList[i-1];   // since lists and arrays use 0-based indexes
```

Comment: You can shorten it a bit by using `var`; `var arrList = new List<int[]>` and `var arr = ...` This is the recommended way.

Comment: That's a style issue.

Comment: @babbupandey And we can shorten everything even more by making variables named a, b, c and so on! But short don't mean readable. Specifying the type explicitly is always better IMO, when you read code you don't want to hover over types all the time to know what they are.

Comment: @babbupandey `var` is not "recommended" by anyone as far as I know - it's just a way to not have to fully name long types like `IEnumerable<IGrouping<MyClass>>` or for anonymous types.  do NOT use `var` for every declaration, especially where the type is _known_.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary:

```
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();
        dictionary.Add("array1", arr1);
        dictionary.Add("array2", arr2);
        dictionary.Add("array3", arr3);

        var arr = dictionary[string.Format("array{0}", i)];
```

Answer (score 0):

use list for performing dynamic operations

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in other answers the way to achieve the dynamism you're looking for is to put all of the arrays in a collection ( `List<int[]>` ) and then you can write more generalized code which operates on the contents of a given array without knowing which array it's operating on at compile time.